# How to draw branched chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is is possible to draw a branched chart like in the picture below using Highcharts?

[image: branched chart]

Comment: Could be done by using more than one line, and just match up your end points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example of matching up the end points.

```
 series: [{
            data: [
                [0, 29.9], 
                [1, 71.5], 
                [2, 100]
            ]
        },{
            data: [
                [2, 100], 
                [3, 150]
            ]
        },{
            data: [
                [2, 100], 
                [3, 50]
            ]
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YmucT/

Comment: + maybe a flag for the bigger circle: http://jsfiddle.net/YmucT/1/ PS: had to use highstock (flags)

Comment: Nice example, but there is still one problem remains for my case. Can I use it with categories? I would like to draw a plot with years. It has to be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YmucT/2/), but I don't want to have '2011 2011 2011' repeating labels in x axis.

Comment: @hagbard you may even be able to use a formatter function to compare this position of y between series and if they match display a custom icon.